# how to filter a table with where

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm trying to filter my table 'mange' with the condition of customers who eat both the "mexicaine" and the "végétarienne".

I have a table 'mange' which contains 'nom' and 'pizza'

I have tried to filter with

```
select *
from mange
where ( pizza = 'végétarienne')
and ( pizza = 'mexicaine')
```

But I don't get anything even though I have some 'nom' who eat both.

Comment: Mexicans do not eat vegetarian pizza, so you are out of luck...... 

Comment: `Group by pizza having count(distinct pizza) = 2` and change `and` to `or` or use `in` or `intersect` or a group by and having...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT nom, count(distinct pizza) as DistinctpizzaCNt
FROM mange
WHERE ( pizza in 'végétarienne', 'mexicaine')
GROUP BY nom
having count(distinct pizza) = 2
```

or use set based logic

```
SELECT nom
FROM mange
WHERE ( pizza = 'végétarienne')

INTERSECT

SELECT nom
from Mannge
WHERE ( pizza = 'mexicaine')
```

Comment: xQbert both solutions work very well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't get anything is because you're trying to evaluate `pizza = 'végétarienne'` and `pizza = 'mexicaine'` at the same time. When a pizza is both vegetarian and mexicane? Never.

That's why you would require the `OR` condition here, to make sure either one of them is retrieved:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mange 
WHERE (pizza = 'végétarienne') OR (pizza = 'mexicaine')
```

In this case you'd retrieve people that eat either one of them, or both. If you want to restrict it to the people that like both and not only one, then you can look for people that like vegetarian, people that like mexicaine and intersect the two sets using the `INTERSECT` operation as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM mange WHERE pizza = 'végétarienne'
INTERSECT 
SELECT * FROM mange WHERE pizza = 'mexicaine'
```

Answer (score 1):

A `WHERE` clause is a Boolean expression that each row is tested against.  Only if a row returns `TRUE` for the whole expression does the row get returned.

So, a `'végétarienne'` row would be tested by your `WHERE` clause and yield `TRUE AND FALSE`, which according to Boolean logic yields `FALSE`.

Similarly, a `'mexicaine'` row would be tested by your `WHERE` clause and yield `FALSE AND TRUE`, which according to Boolean logic also yields `FALSE`.

***Note***: Because no individual row is ever ***both*** `'végétarienne' AND 'mexicaine'`, no row will ever be returned by your `WHERE` clause.

You could either use `OR`, or use `IN()`.  I'd recommend the latter...

```
select *
  from mange
 where ( pizza = 'végétarienne')
    or ( pizza = 'mexicaine')
```

Or...

```
select *
  from mange
 where pizza IN ('végétarienne', 'mexicaine')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not 100% clear to me. My first impression was you are just looking for an `IN` clause to fetch both pizzas, 'végétarienne' and 'mexicaine':

```
SELECT *
FROM mange
WHERE pizza IN ('végétarienne','mexicaine');
```

An `IN` clause will fetch all entries having one of its values.
Since a pizza can't be "végétarienne" and "mexicaine" the same time, we can't build this up using `AND`, but need an `IN` clause or `OR`.

But at second glance, paying attention to your requirement to show *the customers who eat both the "mexicaine" and the "végétarienne"*, this would be an incorrect approach because it would also list such customers who eat only one of them.

So if you are only looking for those customers who eat both pizzas, this can be done this way, using two `IN` clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM mange
WHERE nom
IN
(SELECT nom
FROM mange
WHERE pizza = 'végétarienne')
AND nom 
IN 
(SELECT nom
FROM mange
WHERE pizza = 'mexicaine');
```